# Constructor overload with spread operator Typescript

Tags: typescript

I am trying to overload my constructor for TypeScript Class

```
constructor(a: T[])
constructor(...a: T[]) {
    a.forEach(e => {
        //do something with e
    });
}
```

Why does the compiler complain about the above? And any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Please add the error message to your question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Provided code snippet is not a class. Assuming it is actually wrapped in class. This should work correctly (also in runtime):

```
class A<T> {
    constructor(a: T[]); // first overload
    constructor(...a: T[]); // second overload
    constructor(a) { // implementation (should implement all overloads)
        a = arguments.length === 1 ? a : Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments); 
        a.forEach(e => {
            //do something with e
            console.log(e);
        });
    }
}

var strings = new A<string>(['a']);
var numbers = new A<number>(1, 2, 4);
```

Read more in [Handbook](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#functions-overloads).

Comment: Thanks. I expected the reader to figure out it was wrapped in a class when I said so.

Comment: am I missing the magic syntax for using `private` and `...` in a constructor or is it not possible? `constructor(private ...steps: Step[])`

Comment: Not sure, but I'd guess it is not supported. At least it does not feel right to me to accept multiple parameters as private field.